# How can I add a default header to each HTTP request with Gatling?

Tags: gatling, dynatrace

I'm using Dynatrace and Gatling for performance analysis and testing. Dynatrace supports tracing test runs through the addition of a header to each HTTP request.  I'd like to had that header with a dynamic test guid without adding it to every request individually in 100s of places.

An example test:

```
def GetLocationPage = exec(http(domain + "GetLocationPage")
.post("/location ")
.formParam("updateVersion", "1")
```

I understand that I could add the header individually in each request with...

```
.headers(gatlingHeaders)
```

... but my goal is to avoid doing that 100s of places in the code. Essentially, I'm looking for a Gatling equivalent to [this functionality](http://springinpractice.com/2013/10/27/how-to-send-an-http-header-with-every-request-with-spring-resttemplate) in Spring.

I found [this issue](https://github.com/gatling/gatling/issues/2597) on Gatling, but wasn't able to determine if it would be useful.

Any recommendations?

Comment: This page may be helpful... looking now https://community.dynatrace.com/community/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=213619738

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can configure default headers directly when you are creating your http protocol, e.g.

```
val httpConf = http
   // Here is the root for all relative URLs
   .baseURL("http://computer-database.gatling.io") 
   // Here are the common headers, via specialized methods
  .acceptHeader("text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8") 
  .acceptEncodingHeader("gzip, deflate")
  .acceptLanguageHeader("en-US,en;q=0.5")
  .userAgentHeader("Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.8; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0")
  // More generic methods are available too
  .header("foo", "bar") // to set one header
  .headers(Map("foo" -> "bar", "baz" -> "qix")) // to set a bunch of headers

val scn = scenario("Scenario Name")
  .exec(http("request_1").headers(...) // This is for single request, but you know it already
  .get("/")) // etc...

setUp(scn.inject(atOnceUsers(1)).protocols(httpConf))
```

For more info refer to documentation [Http Headers](http://gatling.io/docs/current/http/http_protocol/#http-headers)